# Alternative to glFramebufferTexture for OpenGL3.1

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

I'm working with hardware that only supports OpenGL3.1, so 'glFramebufferTexture' is not available.

Here's my code at the moment:

```
GLuint frameBuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1,&frameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,frameBuffer);

GLuint depthTexture;
glGenTextures(1,&depthTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,depthTexture);
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
    1024,1024,
    0,
    GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
    GL_FLOAT,
    0
);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE,GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);

// glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,m_depthTexture,0); // Access violation
```

From what I understand, glFramebufferTexture2D should work in a similar fashion

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_TEXTURE_2D,m_depthTexture,0);
```

If I do this however, glCheckFramebufferStatus gives me a 'GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER' error.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

`glFrameBufferTexture (...)` is nothing special, it basically just allows you to do the same thing as 1D, 2D and 3D using a single entry-point. It is ***not*** a hardware limitation as your question suggests, merely a limitation on any driver that does not implement OpenGL 3.2.

As for your framebuffer status, that is actually completely unrelated to this particular API call. This error tells you that you have a non-zero `glReadBuffer (...)` and no corresponding color attachment in your FBO. You can read the formal definition of this error yourself:

> **`GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER`** is returned if **`GL_READ_BUFFER`** is not **`GL_NONE`** and the value of **`GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE`** is **`GL_NONE`** for the color attachment point named by **`GL_READ_BUFFER`**.

Setting `glReadBuffer (...)` is generally not that important. This is used for operations such as `glReadPixels (...)`, and I have seen no indication that your code actually requires this anywhere..

I would suggest you look through your code for any missing attachment points, or errant calls to `glReadBufer (...)`. It sounds an awful lot to me like you are trying to draw into an FBO that has no color buffer attachment, in which case having ***anything*** set other than `GL_NONE` while your FBO is bound is an error.